# Converting string to integer Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am trying to count the number of 0's, positives, negative numbers in array.
I have explicitly converted every string to integer here:

```
k = []
n = int(raw_input())
p=neg=z=0
p = int(p)
neg = int(neg)
z = int(z)

for i in range (0,n):
    numb = int(raw_input("numb: "))
    if numb==0:
        z +=1
    if numb<0:
        neg+=1
    if numb>0:
        p +=1
    k.append(numb)

print "Array: ", k
print '%.5f' %z/n
print '%.5f' % neg/n
print '%.5f' %p/n
```

It keeps giving me this error: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'.

Comment: Try `print '%.5f' % (p/n)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add parens:

```
print "Array: ", k
print '%.5f' % (z / n)
print '%.5f' % (neg / n)
print '%.5f' % (p / n)
```

The format is being done first so you end up trying to `/` the result which is a string by an int. The parens will mean the division etc.. is done and the result is formatted.

You might find using `str.format` less error prone:

```
print '{:.5f}'.format(z / n)
```

Also unless you want the division to floor you should  cast to float not int:

```
n = float(raw_input())
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

> The following table summarizes the operator precedences in Python,
>   from lowest precedence (least binding) to highest precedence (most
>   binding). **Operators in the same box have the same precedence.** Unless
>   the syntax is explicitly given, operators are binary. Operators in the
>   same box group left to right (except for comparisons, including tests,
>   which all have the same precedence and chain from left to right — see
>   section Comparisons — and exponentiation, which groups from right to
>   left).

While studying table we can see row:

```
*, /, //, % Multiplication, division, remainder [8]
```

Footnote [8] says:

> The `%` operator is also used for string formatting; the same precedence
>   applies.

Both `%` and `/` operators has same precedence. Therefore - they are evaluated in standard order. Following equality holds:

```
'%.5f' %z/n == (`%.5f` % z) / n
```

To change evaluation precedence you need to use parentheses.

```
'%.5f' % (z/n)  # It would format string with a result of z/n operation.
```